# JDBC - как установить таймаут на установление соединения?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
SingleConnectionDataSource dataSource = new SingleConnectionDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://".concat(user.getIpAddr()).concat(":").concat(user.getMysqlPort()));
dataSource.setUsername(user.getMysqlLogin());
dataSource.setPassword(user.getMysqlPasswd());
jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

затем я выполняю запрос:

```
extens = jdbcTemplate.query(query, ROW_MAPPER_EXTEN);
```

так вот, если удаленный сервер не отвечает совсем (ну например ошибка в IP адресе), то мне нужно на такой случай установить таймаут.

Я пробовал:

```
try {
    dataSource.setLoginTimeout(100);
} catch (SQLException se) {
    log.warn(se.toString());
}
```

Но в итоге генерируется исключение:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setLoginTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в URL добавить параметр

> connectTimeout=TIME_IN_SEC

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_connect_timeout

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно.